# writing a cron job prgrammatically to crontab file does not run

Tags: java, linux, cron

I am writing a cron job to my crontab file using following java code

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/var/spool/cron/crontabs/multi","UTF-8");
        String cronTabString="25 13 * * * sudo wget --tries=0  \"https://some-url.com:7443/DataUpdater/updateChildren?folderId="+folderId+"&clientId="+clientId+"&clientSecret="+clientSecret+"&refreshToken="+refreshToken+"&deptName="+deptName+"\"";
        writer.println(cronTabString);
        writer.close();
```

The code is successfully writing to cron tab file . But it does not run . My question is that is it even possible to execute a cron job in this manner ? According to me it is a valid cron tab entry , so it should get executed . Am i missing something here ?

Comment: I don't know whether this is a good practice or not. But your `cron` entry probably isn't running due to `sudo`. `sudo` requires the user's password as input.

Comment: i understand its not a good practice , but as stated by @anacron we may have to start or reload the cron daemon . Is that programatically possible ? And if cron tab entry is not running because of sudo , then how i am able to write to the file ?

Comment: Update -- removing sudo does not help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
crontab -r
crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/multi
```

(edit) I believe in Java, you can call these this way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("crontab -r");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/multi");
```

First one removes the existing crontab.  Second one installs the new crontab.  And then you can verify by doing:

```
crontab -l
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!! This did the trick .Would like to know will this also allow me execute more than one cron job at a time by appending it to the crontab file .

Comment: Yes, you should be able to append jobs to the file and reload in this fashion.  Calling 'crontab -r' is not really necessary, but calling it won't touch your file.

Comment: Hmm...will try that too !!  @flu Thanks again !

Comment: @flu - Is there any alternative available for the same solution in javascript? Basically in NodeJS?

Comment: @ShruthiBhaskar - Hi, sorry I'm not familiar with javascript, but this is a shell command.  So I would just check if and how javascript can interact with the shell and invoke a command, then it would likely be possible.

Answer (score 3):

The `crontab` scheduler is not just a file. It is a process that runs as a daemon. When you traditionally edit the crontab file its saves the crontab entries and reload the crontab process. Because of this reason, simply writing to the file will not help. You will need to reload or restart the cron daemon.

> **Update**

You can restart the cron daemon if you have root access on the server by using the following command:

`/etc/init.d/cron reload`

So, in your Java program running on the server, you will need to do this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/etc/init.d/cron reload");`

This will run the system command to restart the cron daemon and reload the cron entries.

Hope this helps!

> **Update 2**

Different flavors of Linux have different commands to restart services or daemons.

You can use this as a good starting point to check which command will go as a parameter into the `exec` method above.

[Cron Command Syntaxes on different Linux Versions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-start-restart-cron/)

Comment: do you have any suggestion that how can we reload or restart the cron daemon , programmatically ? More specifically , using java ?

Comment: Is your Java program running locally on the same server?

Comment: Thank you !! This looks promising . Will give it a try once i'm at my system and let you know the results .

Comment: Your answer was helpful . Coupled with @flu answer , i was able to make it work . Thanks a lot !!